# How to get link url when using select box form method get?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<select name="id">
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

When I submit form is url is "`index.php?id=1`" // or `index.php?id=2`

=> How to fix it is result "`index.php?id=1&name=One`" // or `index.php?id=2&name=Two`

Comment: Is there a reason you need both `ID` and `name`?

Comment: @RobB: I want create a link seo

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to populate the options from a db. Use the values as db ID numbers. Then you can store as much info as you want for each option. example:

```
//some sort of loop{
<option value="
<?php echo $row_option['id'];?>">
<?php echo $row_option['display_text'];?></option> 
}
```

At the other end query db with value; use whatever data need with that value.

Comment: Pretty certain that won't accomplish what the asker wants.